# Dict with sorted keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a built-in `dict` subclass in the Python standard library that keeps the keys in their order, so that `items()` or `keys()` return in the order of keys (I mean not the order of insertion (which `OrderedDict` would do), but the actual relative order of the keys to each other). The equivalent for arrays would be a priority queue, but I haven't heard of anything like this for `dict`s.

Comment: You mean dictionary sorted using keys?

Comment: you mean *sorted* order? No, there is no built-in container that does that. However, there is a pretty good library, [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) which provides various drop-in replacements for built-in types that maintain sorted order. Apparently, it is very efficient, and a pure python implementation to boot!

Comment: There is no such built-in class, but see http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga and Selcuk - I'll check out those links.

Answer (score -1):

Noticed that I missed the part of the question that says "keep it sorted". Some mentions from comments on the original question point to grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html that looks good.

If there is no need to "keep sorted" the following helps.

---

This will do the trick:

```
sorted(my_dict.items())
```

For example:

```
for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(key)
```

** update based on the comments **

If you want to return a dictionary with the sorted order (and guarantee it):

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items()))
```

Comment: This will return a sorted list of tuples, not a sorted dictionary like the OP asks for.

Comment: From what I understand, the order of the dictionary should not matter until you want to use the data, that you can unpack that way. If you need to keep the order static you have to use OrderdDict and manage the sort.

Answer (score -2):

By default, no `dict` keys are not sorted because of the properties of a `dict` object.

Try:

```py
a = {'c': 'd', 'a': 'b', 'e': 'f'}

print(a.keys())
print(sorted(a.keys()))
```

And you can get the keys as a sorted list.

Comment: This will sort the keys only, not the pair key/value

Comment: you said items or keys?

Comment: I'm only interested in the keys, so that works. I'd rather have a solution that doesn't need to be sorted, but which keeps track of the sorting while adding key/values.